# I received an error while trying to run python code based on SUMO simulation

Tags: python, sumo

Here is the error :

> traci.exceptions.TraCIException: The phase index 6 is not in the
> allowed range [0,3]

and I don't understand at all what does this error mean.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: It is hard to tell without any code but I would suspect you try to switch to phase 6 while your traffic light has only four phases.

Comment: @furas I am actually using this algorithm 

https://github.com/AndreaVidali/Deep-QLearning-Agent-for-Traffic-Signal-Control/tree/master/TLCS

then I changed all lanes to become 3 lanes instead of 4 lanes. Then, this error occured

Comment: @Michael 

I think so!, I am still trying to figure out how to solve it.

 I am actually using this algorithm 

https://github.com/AndreaVidali/Deep-QLearning-Agent-for-Traffic-Signal-Control/tree/master/TLCS

then I changed all lanes to become 3 lanes instead of 4 lanes. Then, this error occured.

I am still searching which part from the environment.net.xml should I change.

Comment: I don't understand what "lanes" you mean. And I don't know what all these files has to do.

Comment: You can open your new network in sumo-gui or netedit and right click on the traffic light and show phases. This way you will see how many phases your traffic light has and can compare it  to the one in the original network.